# representing boolean data in sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i am using asp.net application to enter and view data in sql server database.

i am not sure what data type to use in sql server to allow booleans?

when entering data into the database the users will be clicking on a check box to signify true/false.

1. how do i implement bools with sql server?
2. how do i give the ability to the user in formview to enter true/false?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the others said, you can use `BIT` datatype.

However, be warned that if you put `BIT` into a table, and you want only binary values, disable `NULL`.

**If you allow `NULL` in a bit field it will actually be trinary and allow three values.**

Answer (score 3):

Use the BIT column.  In your form just provide a radio button or checkbox.  Here is a helpful link of Sql Data Types compared to .NET types:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use the bit datatype. I would use a checkbox in the gui. If it is not checked then the bit value should be 0, else 1.

Answer (score 2):

One word: bit! (now I am just padding the answer because it is too short)